# Accessing the Rocket 0.4 database connection pool in a request guard

Tags: rust, rust-diesel, rust-rocket

I am creating a webapp with authentication using Rocket. To do this, I created a `User` struct that implements `FromRequest`. It takes the authorization header, which contains a JSON Web Token. I deserialize this token to obtain the payload, and then I query the user from the database. This means that the `FromRequest` implementation needs a `diesel::PgConnection`. In Rocket 0.3 this meant calling `PgConnection::establish`, but with Rocket 0.4 we have access to a connection pool. Normally I would access this connection pool as follows:

```
fn get_data(conn: db::MyDatabasePool) -> MyModel {
    MyModel::get(&conn)
}
```

However, within the impl block for `FromRequest` I can not just add the `conn` argument to the argument list of `from_request` function. How do I access my connection pool outside of a request guard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rocket [guide for database state](https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/state/#databases) says:

> Whenever a connection to the database is needed, use your [database pool] type as a request guard

Since a database pool can be created via `FromRequest` and you are implementing `FromRequest`, use the existing implementation via `DbPool::from_request(request)`:

```
use rocket::{
    request::{self, FromRequest, Request},
    Outcome,
};

// =====
// This is a dummy implementation of a pool
// Refer to the Rocket guides for the correct way to do this
struct DbPool;

impl<'a, 'r> FromRequest<'a, 'r> for DbPool {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn from_request(_: &'a Request<'r>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        Outcome::Success(Self)
    }
}
// =====

struct MyDbType;

impl MyDbType {
    fn from_db(_: &DbPool) -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

impl<'a, 'r> FromRequest<'a, 'r> for MyDbType {
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn from_request(request: &'a Request<'r>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let pool = DbPool::from_request(request);
        pool.map(|pool| MyDbType::from_db(&pool))
    }
}
```